# CStatic::GetWindow() does not return window of the current control

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to paint some colors intro dialog that i have several buttons(for picking color) and a `CStatic` control which window I'm going to use in order to paint the selected color in it. 
However when i call `m_myStatic.GetWindow( NULL )` a pointer to the first button's window is returned. 
When i call `GetWindow( GW_HWNDLAST )` a pointer to the static control window is returned, just because it is last placed in the dialog(in the bottom).

As long as I can see in the documentation [CWnd::GetWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex4cy2e.aspx) is documented to be not virtual an therefore when it is called it does not return the window of the caller control.

My question is: 
How do i get the window of a static control and be sure that a pointer to the current window is being returned despite of the placement?

Comment: `m_myStatic` _is_ the `CWnd` you need, right?

Comment: Yes. And it is instance of CStatic.

Comment: Job done then. What's your question?

Comment: I know the job is done, however I don't know if calling m_myStatic.GetWindow( GW_HWNDLAST ) will work in any case in which the control is not last in order in the host window. 
It seems really strange that 
m_myStatic.GetWindow(NULL) does not return self window.

Comment: Why would it return the self window? You _already have_ the self window...

Comment: `GetWindow(NULL)` is not valid, see documentation. May be you are looking for `CWnd *wnd = &m_myStatic;` to get `CWnd*` object?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, yes - that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Quite amusing question it was!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CWnd::GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex4cy2e.aspx) calls [::GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515.aspx), passing `m_hWnd` as the first argument, and your `nCmd` as the second argument.

`NULL` is `#define NULL 0`, so that's exactly the same as calling `GetWindow(m_hWnd, 0)`, and `GW_HWNDFIRST` is also defined as `0`, so all you're doing is:

```
CWnd *w = m_myStatic.GetWindow(GW_HWNDFIRST);
```

...which is documented as returning the first sibling of `m_myStatic`.

---

If all you want is a `CWnd *` from `m_myStatic`, bear in mind that `m_myStatic` is an instance of `CStatic`, which is derived from `CWnd` (see the [CStatic documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98kd6f7.aspx)), so can simply use `&m_myStatic` wherever a `CWnd *` is required, because `CStatic *` is implicitly convertible to `CWnd *`.